# Мониторинг ресурсов сервера средствами

Tags: php, ram, cpu, сервер

Интересует, как с помощью Php можно узнать текущую нагрузку на систему, количество занятого места и т.д. Можно ли как-то это сделать?

Comment: > количество занятого места 

[disk_free_space](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.disk-free-space.php)

> текущую нагрузку на систему

[sys_getloadavg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-getloadavg.php)

для остального можно использовать системыне команды и `system()` для их вызова, в линуксе многое можно прочитать из файлов в каталоге `/proc`

Comment: @Fike даже не думал что специальные функции есть.. Думал все через команды придется делать. Спасибо

Comment: @M11, ну, скорее всего эти функции дергают те же сишные функции, что и обычные терминальные команды, никакой магии, в общем. Но если лишний раз текстовый вывод не парсит, то и хорошо.

Comment: Может, не php таки, а [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сервер на Linux, то предложу постуть следующим образом:

Идем сюда и качаем код панельки управления https://github.com/afaqurk/linux-dash

Там в файлах модулей вычленяем код, который Вам нужен. Там очень очевидно все, думаю сложностей не вызовет. Сам вчера оттуда брал)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения загрузки ЦПУ можно использовать что-то вроде этого:

```php
public static function getServerCPULoad(){

  //проверяем возможность чтения виртуальной директории
  if (@is_readable('/proc/stat')){

    //делаем первый замер
    $file_first = file("/proc/stat");

    //определяем значения состояний (описаны выше)
    $tmp_first = explode(" ",$file_first[0]);

    $cpu_user_first = $tmp_first[2];
    $cpu_nice_first = $tmp_first[3];
    $cpu_sys_first = $tmp_first[4];
    $cpu_idle_first = $tmp_first[5];
    $cpu_io_first = $tmp_first[6];

    sleep(2);//промежуток до второго замера

    //делаем второй замер
    $file_second = file("/proc/stat");
    $tmp_second = explode(" ",$file_second[0]);

    $cpu_user_second= $tmp_second[2];
    $cpu_nice_second= $tmp_second[3];
    $cpu_sys_second = $tmp_second[4];
    $cpu_idle_second= $tmp_second[5];
    $cpu_io_second = $tmp_second[6];

    //определяем разницу использованного процессорного времени
    $diff_used = ($cpu_user_second-$cpu_user_first)+($cpu_nice_second-$cpu_nice_first)+($cpu_sys_second-$cpu_sys_first)+($cpu_io_second-$cpu_io_first);

    //определяем разницу общего процессорного времени
    $diff_total = ($cpu_user_second-$cpu_user_first)+($cpu_nice_second-$cpu_nice_first)+($cpu_sys_second-$cpu_sys_first)+($cpu_io_second-$cpu_io_first)+($cpu_idle_second-$cpu_idle_first);

    //определение загрузки cpu
    $cpu = round($diff_used/$diff_total, 2);

    return $cpu; (от 0 до 1, если нужно в % - x100)
  }
  return null;
}
```

Взято [отсюда](http://valerij.pp.ua/cpu-load-php-linux/) - там есть описание что что означает + [описание с википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.8F.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.86.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B0)